# map over properties in array and concat a string in JavaScript es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

I have the following array of objects for example some authors and I want to map through them and return a string which has been concatenated with some formatting. I am for some reason having an issue with this fairly easy thing.

```
const authors = [ { id: 1, name: 'Steven'}, {id: 2, name: 'Nick'}]
let names = authors.map( (a, i) => {
  return `${a.name} is cool`
})
console.log(names)
// ["Steven is cool","Nick is cool"]
// but I really want the string "Steven is cool Nick is cool"
```

How can I instead get this to map through and format it to a string?

e.g. `"Steven is cool Nick is cool"`

Comment: Your brwoser , and its version ?

Comment: Just `names.join(" ")`?

Answer (score 30):

Use `Array#Join` :

```
authors.map((a) => `${a.name} is cool`).join(' ');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/2btx0c28/2/)

---

NOTE : `join` is not related to ES6 , it is old .

Comment: @steveniseki : i update answer, i make code more elegant (brief)

Comment: _"i make code more elegant (brief)"_   `(a) =>` can be `a =>` for that matter

Comment: Yep @abetteroliver, it matters because it does not comply with eslint rules; Check out aribnb JS coding conventions.

Comment: I am confused. If you want your code to comply then why don't you change it?

Answer (score 5):

i for one prefer the use of reduce

ES5 version

```
autors.reduce(function (str, person) { 
  return (str+' '+person.name+ ' is cool');
}, '');
```

ES6 version

```
autors.reduce((str, person) => `${str} ${person.name} is cool`, '');
```

Comment: Why would you use `reduce` rather than `join` for this?

Comment: thanks another good option, more of a functional approach and works well

Comment: @demux it's not so much `reduce()` rather than `join()`, but `reduce()` rather than `map().join()`. `map().join()` has to loop through all of the elements in the array twice, whereas `reduce()` only does a single loop. So, `reduce()` performs better (2x). This gain is, practically speaking, meaningless unless your array is VERY big, OR if you are doing it VERY (VERY) often. But, I think it's worth thinking about these things even on a small scale so that, when it matters, you notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version so you don't have to map --> join.. you can just reduce.

```
const authors = [ { id: 1, name: 'Steven'}, {id: 2, name: 'Nick'}]

console.log(authors.reduce( (p,c) => `${p} ${c.name} is cool `, ""))
```

Comment: `map->join` is the most performance . Check : https://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/2btx0c28/4/

Comment: I believe reduce will always more performant because it doesn't have to create a intermediary array. Also, in your fiddle, in chrome - reduce is more performant. But I tend to fluctuate between a reduce and a map/join solution. Depends on how I am feeling.

Comment: This will leave a space at the beginning.

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI If you want to test performance, then use a dedicated framework. Simple time measuring is pointless.